# algorithm complexity - what double star means

Tags: php, algorithm, big-o, complexity-theory, time-complexity

Does anybody know what means doubled-star in complexity algorithm like this `O(N**3)`? I found that one in PHP's [similar_text()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.similar-text.php) function and do not understand it.

thx

Answer (score 7, accepted):

** means power. Hence, n**3 means n^3. Complexity is of the order n^3 or O(n^3)

Answer (score 5):

This double star is the exponentiation operator in PHP(^ operator in general for exponentiation).

As per PHP manual,

```
$a ** $b ---- Exponentiation Operator   
Result of raising $a to the $b'th power. Introduced in PHP 5.6.
```

hence, here the complexity is O(n^3),i.e., O of (n raised to power 3) OR cubic complexity.

Answer (score 3):

It's not always easy to write mathematics when you're only allowed ASCII, so often writers resort to using operators found in programming languages as a way of concisely representing the mathematics.

In some languages, `**` means exponentiation, and this is what it means here. ASCII doesn't have a superscript, so it's impossible to represent exponentiation in standard mathematical notation if you're restricted to ASCII. The fact that you found this in a PHP context is a further clue, since PHP is one of the languages that uses `**` for exponentiation.

`O(n**3)` means *O*(n<sup>3</sup>).

Answer (score 0):

`**` star is short hand for raise to power(and also a valid operator in some languages). This is the same as `N^3`. Thus the function has cubic complexity.